# What is the meaning of "I see shadow and light stroking the mist" from “Moonlight Kissed”?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, poets-of-the-fall

Poets of the Fall released their song [“Moonlight Kissed”](https://genius.com/Poets-of-the-fall-moonlight-kissed-lyrics) on 22nd September 2017 along with a video. However, the very first line of the song

> I see shadow and light stroking the mist

is quite poetic and I’m unable to comprehend it fully. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

From [AtmosphericOptics.com](http://www.atoptics.co.uk/rayshad.htm)

> Dust, small aerosols and moisture droplets scatter light to make the
> sun's rays visible

This obviously applies to the moon's rays as well, so the water droplets that form the mist, scatter the light making it visible in the air, where objects block the light they cast shadows in the illuminated mists creating rays.
'Stroking' may mean that the writer percieves the light falling on the mist as though it was lightly touching it, or it may be more metaphorical and be intended to evoke paintstrokes with the light painting the canvas of the mist.

[image]